# Parsing log files in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, logging

I am working through the online materials for [CIS 194, a upenn haskell class](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/03-rec-poly.pdf) (not taking the class). This exercise is to parse an error log, and it gives a few function signatures to implement, ending with the very last one `whatWentWrong`. Please help me make the code more idiomatic, particularly `whatWentWrong`. My haskell level is: understood LYAH but have not written much code.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
module LogAnalysis where

import Log -- https://github.com/dustingetz/sandbox/tree/master/cis194/hw2


parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage s = case words s of
  -- I 5053 pci_id: con ing!
  ("I":t:msg) -> LogMessage Info (read t) (unwords msg)

  -- W 3654 e8] PGTT ASF!
  ("W":t:msg) -> LogMessage Warning (read t) (unwords msg)

  -- E 47 1034 'What a pity it
  ("E":sev:t:msg) -> LogMessage (Error $ read sev) (read t) (unwords msg)

  _ -> Unknown s


parse :: String -> [LogMessage]
parse s = map parseMessage $ lines s


insert :: LogMessage -> MessageTree -> MessageTree
insert (Unknown _) node = node
insert m Leaf = Node Leaf m Leaf
insert m@(LogMessage _ t _) (Node l' m'@(LogMessage _ t' _) r')
  | t <= t' = Node (insert m l') m' r'
  | t > t' = Node l' m' (insert m r')


build :: [LogMessage] -> MessageTree
build ms = foldl (flip insert) Leaf ms

inOrder :: MessageTree -> [LogMessage]
inOrder (Node l m r) = inOrder l ++ [m] ++ inOrder r
inOrder Leaf = []

--fmap ((take 10) . inOrder . build) $ testParse parse 100 "error.log"

whatWentWrong :: [LogMessage] -> [String]
whatWentWrong ms = map (\(LogMessage _ _ s) -> s) $
                   filter (\(LogMessage msgType _ _) ->
                            case msgType of
                             Error sev -> sev >= 50
                             _ -> False) $
                   inOrder $ build ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Concerning `whatWentWrong`, the main problem is that the function isn't [total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_functional_programming). This means that for `Unknown` it will fail badly and unconditionally.

If you declare the functions from `map` and `filter` as named functions in a `where` (or `let` block), you will be able to check for `Unknown` as well in pattern matching. Also, you can combine several constructors in a pattern.

There are two options how to fix `map`: Either return some `String` for `Unknown`, or remove such entries. I'll show an example for the latter option using [`mapMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe):

```
whatWentWrong :: [LogMessage] -> [String]
whatWentWrong = mapMaybe getMsg
                . filter filterExp
                . inOrder . build
  where
    filterExp (LogMessage (Error sev) _ _) = sev >= 50
    filterExp _                            = False
    getMsg (LogMessage _ _ s) = Just s
    getMsg _                  = Nothing
```

Also note that you can declare this function as a composition of functions, in so-called [point-free style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree).